# .NET 4.5 Universal Membership Provider table names

Tags: .net, sql, asp.net-mvc, universal-provider

Is there any way to prefix the new .NET 4.5 DefaultMembershipProvider table names in the database? They used to be named aspnet_Users, aspnet_Roles etc. and they are now named just Users, Roles, etc. which is conflicting with my application schema that has a table User.

Is my only option to use a separate database for membership if I want to use the new universal providers and avoid this naming issue?

Comment: Why are you putting them into the exact same database? They should be seperate.  You should question the wisdom of using your own tables without a prefix.

Comment: That is a matter of opinion, it's common to do both, which is why the .NET framework includes the aspnet_regsql.exe tool. Unfortunately with .NET 4.5 this tool assumes the legacy provider.

Comment: Also, the new Universal provider will create its tables in your database at runtime (if they don't exist) using your default connection string. So unless you specify a new database for the membership provider, it's going in your application database.

I would not consider prefixing my own tables to be wise. My tables are not being injected into anyone's application, but the membership tables are by design.

Comment: Part of the reason for using the universal providers is their support of SQL Compact Edition and SQL Azure. If you plan to use your application on SQL Azure, and you think you may need your membership tables participating in a transaction, then locating them in the same database is the only way, otherwise you'll end up requiring MS DTC which isn't going to work on Azure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to customize the table names for the Universal Providers currently, I'll make sure we consider adding support for this in the future.

Comment: We ended up using a separate database for the membership tables

Comment: Being able to specify a schema other than "dbo" would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to have DefaultMembershipProvider use tables under a different schema by having it connect to SQL with a login which maps to a non-default schema (e.g. "membership") in the target database.  In SSMS, look at the Login Properties, User Mapping, Default Schema.  That way, the application's `[dbo].[Users]` would not conflict with `[membership].[Users]`.