# Is RoleProvider needed to use [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I would like to use the [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] attribute on my ASP.net MVC controller actions. Do I need to have a role provider configured (either out of the box or custom) to do this? If I do, and I want to use a custom role provider, which method(s) must be implemented in order to use the AuthorizeAttribute?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need Role Provider in order to use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`

Take a look at new [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) which uses Entity Framework Code First.

(Note: Old ASP.Net Membership Provider generated by aspnet_regsql.exe uses schema and store procedures. I do not recommend using it.)

If you want to implement **Custom Role Provider**, minimum you need to override the following method (other methods are optional) -

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
```

### Updated for Comment

> if I have to use a MembershipProvider or can I get away with just
>   using a RoleProvider to use [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] on my
>   controller actions

Normally, you want to use MembershipProvider if you want to use RoleProvider. Otherwise, you will need to create IPrincipal object and add the user's authorized roles to the object.

> According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455676/net-4-5-universal-membership-provider-table-names), you cannot customize [map] with Universal
>   Providers.

The original question is about renaming the membership tables which you cannot do (unless you create *Custom Membership Provider and Custom Role Provider*). However, you can create relationships between your tables and membership tables. In addition, you can include membership tables in your store procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and direct answer. You mentioned ASP.net Universal Providers using Entity Framework, which I have little experience with as of yet. Could I map the entity classes to my own procedures and tables (which I understand is one of the features/benefits of EF)?

Comment: Actually, you do not need to know Entity Framework to use Universal Providers - they are under the hood. ***You can map with your store procedures and tables as long as you do not alter their tables such as adding extra columns to Users table (which is NO NO).***

Comment: Thanks, but won't I have to know EF if I want to map my tables and procedures? How else would I do the mapping if not in EF?

Comment: Also, do you know if I have to use a MembershipProvider or can I get away with just using a RoleProvider to use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` on my controller actions?

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455676/net-4-5-universal-membership-provider-table-names), you cannot customize [map] with Universal Providers.

Comment: I updated the answer. If you have any question regarding EF, please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to have membership/role provider configured to use Authorize(Roles = "Admin"). When you create asp.net mvc project it automatically configured for u. If you use the tool aspnet_regsql.exe  it will create membership database. 
Following link may help

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7

To implement custom role provider is bit difficult and lot of coding involve. 
Please see the following link

http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx

http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx

http://bojanskr.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/custom-membership-provider.html
http://bojanskr.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/custom-role-provider.html
http://bojanskr.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/syntaxhighlighter.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx